# Error with UNION in an INSERT INTO request

Tags: mysql, union, insert-into

I have a weird issue in MYSQL :

```
Error in query (1054): Unknown column db2.d.id_d in 'on clause'
```

My query is :

```
INSERT INTO db1.p (db1.f)
(SELECT CONCAT(db2.d.df, '_', db2.dp.dfp) AS dfp
FROM db2.dp
LEFT OUTER JOIN db2.d ON db2.d.id = db2.dp.id_d)
UNION
(SELECT CONCAT(db3.d.df, '_', db3.dp.dfp) AS dfp
FROM db3.dp
LEFT OUTER JOIN db3.d ON db3.d.id = db3.dp.id_d)
```

I can confirm you that the db2.d.id_d column EXIST the error 
come from UNION because the first part of request :

```
INSERT INTO db1.p (db1.f)
(SELECT CONCAT(db2.d.df, '_', db2.dp.dfp) AS dfp
FROM db2.dp
LEFT OUTER JOIN db2.d ON db2.d.id = db2.dp.id_d)
```

Work perfectly.

On other thread I see all the request worked but without INNER JOIN.
Perhabs the INNER JOIN is concern.
I don't know ...

Comment: `select id_d from db2.d` works fine?

Comment: In your query, what does `INSERT INTO db1.p (db1.f)` do (since you say it is working)?

Comment: Of course `select id_d from db2.d` works fine.  `INSERT INTO db1.p (db1.f)` when I said it's working : CONCAT 2 column in 1 in db1.p it's do what I want but only for one DB. My goal its to JOIN 2 result of 2 different DB with the same column name, and INSERT INTO another DB

Comment: Ok, to be more precise: `INSERT INTO db1.p (db1.f)` is already not working, because `db1.f` is not a valid column. So you are probably using a different query. Guessing what else is not exactly like your original query is hard. Either post your exact query or look for the column in your query. The error message is pretty precise.

Comment: I'm saying again if I remove all down `UNION` (with UNION) The query work fine.

Comment: `db1.f` is not a column of the table `db1.p`. So your query, as written there, cannot work. So this is not exactly the query you are using. If you are looking for an error in your query that is probably just a speeling error, please provide the exact query. And, to make sure, the `show create table`- statements for your table.